# differentiate TI-89

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculator

I want to differentiate x^n on the calculater ti-89, but when I use the 
differentiate function i get: 
2nd -> F3 -> d(x^a,x) = Error: dimension

is it not possible to differentiate with letters in TI-89? I know the answer to the equation, but I want to know ho to do it in TI-89.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: [Look at this][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20differentiate%20partial%20functions%20ti-89&oq=how%20to%20differentiate%20partial%20functions%20ti-89&gs_l=psy-ab.3...13637.14833.0.15080.8.8.0.0.0.0.211.827.0j4j1.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0.-Jee5nVsRC0#kpvalbx=1

Comment: There's got to be some kind of TI-89 forum where this would be more appropriate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

dimension error usually means that there is too much to process or display, you should consult your guide

Comment: how do I consult my guide?

Comment: The manual that came with the ti-89

Comment: Now it works thank you very much! :)